# Downloading multipolygons and indexing them

Tags: polygon, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I'm trying to download Sentinel-2 data of my area of interest.

My shapefile contains two different polygons. So when I try to download the output images I get the error:

> Error creating or submitting task.
>   A region must be a GeoJSON Polygon or LinearRing. Got: '*MultiPolygon*'.

```
 Export.image.toDrive({   
    image: collection_aoi,
    description: date + '_S2_BOA_cloudfree',
    maxPixels: 1000000000000,
   scale: 10,
   region: aoi,
    });
```

Is there any way to index polygons out of the "MultiPolygon" shapefile? I don't want to upload separate Polygons because in the future I will be using more polygons in the shapefile.